# Is it possible to connect 3 monitors with Dell Slim Studio 540S

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hardware-rec, dell-studio

I bought a graphic card, ATI Radeon HD 4350 DMS59 512 MB DDR2 PCIe 2.0 SFF Graphic Card, trying to connect a third monitor, but it disables the original on-board graphic card. So is it Is it possible to connect 3 monitors with Dell Slim Studio 540S?

Answer (score 2):

Windows supports up to 9 displays natively, so its the hardware thats limiting you.  Some BIOSs detect that you put in a video card and disable the onboard graphics card.  There might be a setting in BIOS to keep it enabled.  Look under "integrated devices" or something similar to that.

Another thing to note is that there are known issues in Windows 7 when trying to use 2 different video drivers.

Comment: The operating system I have on the Slim Studio 540S is Windows Vista, not Windows 7. Can I still set it up in BIOS to make both the on-board graphic card and the new card work?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about using an on board graphics card, but you could buy a [splitter](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?hl=en&safe=off&qscrl=1&q=dvi+splitter&gs_upl=3669l5621l0l5664l12l10l0l4l4l0l253l1139l1.5.1l7l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&biw=1280&bih=737&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=3390101337862261215&sa=X&ei=TGxxTv7qGOPb0QHbs7DwCQ&ved=0CEsQ8wIwAg), products of that type should do fine.

Comment: Will a splitter make duplicated displays or an extended display?

Comment: If its just a splitter, then duplicated displays.  However if your willing to spend significantly more, you can buy a device that essentially has its own graphics card, that lets you use an extended Diplay.

Comment: An alternative if you have another computer to waste, is http://synergy-foss.org/ It lets you use your mouse/keyboard across another computer.

Comment: @wizlog, will the device that essentially has its own graphics card disable the on-board graphic card? because I can connect the original on-board card with 2 monitors with both working, and I just want one additional port that can be used for the 3rd monitor.

Answer (score 0):

> I bought a graphic card, ATI Radeon HD 4350 DMS59 512 MB DDR2 PCIe 2.0
>   SFF Graphic Card.

OK, that is a dedicated graphics card which allows you to connect two monitors via DMS59...

> I am trying to connect a third monitor, 
>   but it disables the original on-board graphic card.

The graphics card can not disable your other on-board graphics. What can happen is that your motherboards firmware (BIOS) is trying to be to smart.

Usually you can use:

- On-board graphics only
- dedicated graphics only
- Or both on-board graphics and dedicated graphics.

What I suspect is that the BIOS detected a dedicated card and tries to turn the on-board off, thus freeing up some more resources. Which is bloody anoying when firmware does this on its own.  To prevent this go to the BIOS and set the on-board graphics to 'enabled' (not to 'auto').

So is it Is it possible to connect 3 monitors with Dell Slim Studio 540S?